# Parsing error in ArrayList<Integer> in jdeveloper 10g

Tags: java, arraylist, parsing-error

I am trying to do a simple program using `ArrayList<Intger>` in jdeveloper 10g, but it's giving a parsing error. I have also tried the same code in an online editor and it's working perfectly fine.

Here's my code

```
 import java.util.*;

 class TestCollection1
 {
      public static void main(String args[])
      {
           ArrayList<Integer> a = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           a.add(1);
           a.add(2);
           a.add(3);
           Iterator i = a.iterator();
           while(i.hasNext())
           {
                System.out.println(i.next());
           }
      }  
 }
```

This image shows the compiler error:

[image: compiler error in jdeveloper 10g]

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to a more recent IDE, [JDeveloper 10g](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/soft10g-090292.html) (from the release notes) *Oracle JDeveloper 10g (10.1.2.3, Build 1936) - for Windows NT/2000/XP, Linux, Solaris, HP-UX, and Macintosh.* **and** *Complete Install
includes Windows JDK 1.4.2*; [generics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java) were added to Java in version 1.5 (released in 2004). Your version predates that, and is [end of life](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/eol-135779.html).